# Calling a C dll function which gets char** from C#

Tags: c#, c

I have a C dll that exports a function that looks like this:

```c
void GetSectionData(TCHAR name [], char **Address, DWORD * Size)
```

The function gets a name and returns the Address after it was allocated with `*Size` bytes. Here is an example of how to use the function in C:

```c
char *addr[64]:
DWORD Size[64];
TCHAR name[260];
sprintf( name, "myDll.dll);
GetSectionAddress(name, &addr[index],&Size[index]);
```

I want to use this dll function in C# without `unsafe`.
My function Declaration should use the `DllImport` attribute but I dont know how to declare the parameters, mainly the Address and Size parameters (I assume that name can be declared as `StringBuilder`):

```cs
[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
public static extern void GetSectionData(?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your pinvoke signature would be

```
static extern void GetSectionData(string name, out string address, out int size);
```

but:

- at 'adress' parameter, you *may* need to indicate the relation to 'size' by `[MarshalAs]` attribute and proper SizeIndex value. If you change the 'out string' to 'out char[]' then surely it will be required, but if you use string and if your returned string is a normal null-terminated string, I think it will not be necessary
- if the function allocates the memory for `address` array, you might encounter some problems as the usage of the function will assume that the caller must know how to free it.. please see i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932956/717732 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274007/717732 - the main problem is that there are really many ways to allocate the buffer (including stack-based temporary arrays..) and the caller will have hard time guessing. Especially the marshaller used in p/invoke, as it does not know anything about your code..

Answer (score 0):

According to Reflector, the way .Net Framework does this internally is to pass a `StringBuilder` instance into the char** parameter, while other (numeric) pointers are often passed in as `IntPtr`. A good example is `FormatMessage`, which has the following signature:

```
DWORD WINAPI FormatMessage(
  _In_      DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_opt_  LPCVOID lpSource,
  _In_      DWORD dwMessageId,
  _In_      DWORD dwLanguageId,
  _Out_     LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  _In_      DWORD nSize,
  _In_opt_  va_list *Arguments
);
```

is defined under `Microsoft.Win32.SafeNativeMethods` as

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int FormatMessage(int dwFlags, HandleRef lpSource, int dwMessageId, int dwLanguageId, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr arguments);
```

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`, which invokes this method, does

```
int error = 0; //Error code, for example
StringBuilder lpBuffer = new StringBuilder(0x100);
SafeNativeMethods.FormatMessage(0x3200, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, error, 0, lpBuffer, lpBuffer.Capacity + 1, IntPtr.Zero)
```

If you want to extract the size parameter, you may define an unsafe method, and actually use the type `int*` for the size parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
public static extern void GetSectionData(StringBuilder name, ref IntPtr Address, ref int32 Size);